# ASP.NET Running application with local DB on any machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, wcf

I am creating this WCF service which uses 5 tables on my local database. I want to keep the connection string to just use my local database(and anyone using it around me) because this application is only a week long to build and won't be used after this week. Is there a way to set up scripts within asp.net to autogenerate my local database on anyones local machine that way they can run my application fine. I know right now if they would attempt this, the application would break because they dont have the tables I have on my local machine.

Comment: If you're using EntityFramework Code first it automatically generates schema with local db connection string when running first time. Simply consider the default asp.net project template with Individual user account. When you run this default template first time it will automatically creates schema in local db instance.

Comment: You could use Sql Server Management Studio to script the database to a file, and then when the service runs, check if the DB exists, and if not then run the create script.

Comment: I will check if i can use code Entity Framework within a wcf service. As for the second solution, ive never heard of that but that is interesting. I am going to have to check into that.